# Specify page range for lpr command

Tags: linux, printing, lpr

According to docs, `lpr` command doesn’t have an option which specifies the number of pages that should be printed. Is it possible to specify a page range for printing with `lpr` command somehow, may be through piping?

Answer (score 2):

What “docs” are you looking at? The [official CUPS page for `lpr`](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html) shows the following:

> **Selecting a Range of Pages**
>
> The `-o page-ranges=pages` option selects a range of pages for printing:
>
> ```
> lp -o page-ranges=1 filename
> lp -o page-ranges=1-4 filename
> lp -o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12 filename
> lpr -o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12 filename
> ```